# MVC Entity Framework Select field from other entity when is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework application. I am migrating  stored procedures to lambda expressions.

I have two tables, one of them is the `Configuration` table where I have default values.

I am doing a `select from table1` and if a column is null, I take the default value from table2.

In SQL Server, I have this:

```
Select 
    field1, field2, field3,
    isnull(field4, (select fieldXX from Table2 with (nolock))) as field4
from 
    Table1 with (nolock)
```

Is it possible to do it in Entity Framework?

Thanks

Comment: the answer you up voted does not work.  Please see other answers.  Can you please let me know if this works, and tell me if you want me to linqify the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer below, so that it contains a single select.  I am not saying that Ashiquzzaman did not solve it, but I just can't get his/her solution to work.

Comment: Can you do this as a join instead of a subquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
var result= from p in Table1
         select new 
         {
           field1= p.field1,
           field2= p.field2,
           field3= p.field3,
           field4= p.field4==null?(from c in Table2 select c.fieldXX).FirstOrDefault():p.field4
         }.ToList();
```

Comment: This gets a operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type string and system.linq.Iqueryable<string>

Comment: It Works fine, but I mist to say that field4 is a byte[] type, and it is not allow using ?? for byte types... How can I do it ? thanks

Comment: @Diego sorry for my previous answer. I just miss `FirstOrDefault`. I update my answer. Please try this now.

Answer (score 0):

First add the tables and data:

```
--I use db Breaz, you use whatever you require
USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[table1]    Script Date: 5/4/2017 12:20:45 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [field1] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [field2] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [field3] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [field4] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[table2]    Script Date: 5/4/2017 12:20:45 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table2](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Field4Default] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_table2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table1] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Id], [field1], [field2], [field3], [field4]) VALUES (1, N'f1', N'f2', N'f3', N'f4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([Id], [field1], [field2], [field3], [field4]) VALUES (2, N'seconda', N'secondb', N'secondc', NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table1] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table2] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[table2] ([Id], [Field4Default]) VALUES (3, N'DefaultV')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table2] OFF
GO
```

Add EDMX:  Right click on Models folder and add ADO.NET Entity Data Model.  Name It table1 and click Ok, Generate from database is highlighted, so click Next.  Click New Connection.  Enter Server Name.  Use windows authentication or use sql server authentication(credentials) and if latter, click save my password.  Select the database from the dropdown.  Click Ok.  Wait to click 'yes, include the sensitive..', if you did windows authentication.  Copy to clipboard the connection below 'save entity connection..'.  Click next.  Under tables, choose table1 and table2.  Click finish.  And click ok for the next two prompts (wait for them), and close the gui designer.

This is your controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index63()
    {
        var table1List = new List<table1>();
        //instead of BreazEntities18,  use the name you copied to the clipboard
        //or lick on table1.context.cs to get the name
        using (BreazEntities18 entity = new BreazEntities18())
        {
            var q = entity.table1.Select(r => new
            {
                field1 = r.field1,
                field2 = r.field2,
                field3 = r.field3,
                field4 = r.field4 == null ? (entity.table2.Select(s => s.Field4Default).FirstOrDefault())
                                : r.field4
            }
                ).ToList();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: I have done like this, what I pretend to do, is to do it in a single Select. thanks

Comment: @Diego I updated my answer below, so that it contains a single select.  I am not saying that Ashiquzzaman did not solve it, but I just can't get his/her solution to work.